# How do i fix this issue in the java, where my geofence is not working?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Th geofencing that I try to implement to my app is not working, no errors but the geofence is not triggering and it doesn't even show any sign that the geofence is even implemented as if the whole geofence objects I add doesn't exist, can you see any problem with this code?

```
package com.research.pawthfinder;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private Marker marker;
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 1;
    private Geofence geofence;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;
    private GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest;
    private PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;
    private static final String TAG = "MapFragment";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(getActivity());

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Dog#1"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17));
            }
        };
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng geocenter = new LatLng(14.5979, 121.0108);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Set up geofencing client
            geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(getActivity());
            geofencePendingIntent = null;
            geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId("GeofenceID")
                    .setCircularRegion(geocenter.latitude, geocenter.longitude, 200)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build();

            // Set up geofencing request
            geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                    .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                    .addGeofence(geofence)
                    .build();

            // Set up pending intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
            intent.setAction("com.research.pawthfinder.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ENTERED");
            geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Add geofence
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, geofencePendingIntent)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Geofence added successfully");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to add geofence", e);
                            }
                        });
            }

            // Add circle to map
            CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            circleOptions.center(geocenter);
            circleOptions.radius(200);
            circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.argb(255, 0,255,0));
            circleOptions.fillColor(Color.argb(64, 0, 255,0));
            mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Also this is my Broadcast Receiver as well is want to see it

```
package com.research.pawthfinder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyReceiver";
    private NotificationHelper notificationHelper;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            return;
        }
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
            Geofence geofence = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences().get(0);
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = geofence.getRequestId() + " " + getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);
            Log.d(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
            // send notification
            notificationHelper.sendHighPriorityNotification("Geofence Transition", geofenceTransitionDetails, MapFragment.class);
        }
    }

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return "entered";
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return "exited";
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

I actually have no idea what's wrong with this code as there are no errors that occur when i try to run the program it just shows me my location, I also put a log when the geofence is added, but it doesn't show up to.

Comment: Is your problem that the geofence isn't visible even though the map and location are?